# install Conky-master from zip fali

Tags: 16.04

I downloaded `conky-master.zip`. When I unzip this I see some files, that I don't know what should I do with them.

[image: when i unzip IMG]

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Readme.md` file that you should open and read. It should contains instructions on how install `conky`.

Anyway, since there is an `INSTALL` file, you can try to install `conky` running that file. So open a terminal, place terminal working directory inside `conky` folder with this command:

```
cd <file-location>
```

and run the following command that will execute `INSTALL` file:

```
./INSTALL
```

Now follow instructions on the screen. At the process end you should have installed `conky`.

I hope this could help you.

---

P.S. In any case, I recommend to you to read the `Readme` file every time you are not sure on what to do. Often is enough clear to help you to carry out your task.